# Why is for loop trying to access element outside range of list?

Tags: python-2.7, list, keyerror

When iterating over a list I am getting a key error, I am confused as to why since I am iterating from 0 to range(len(list))

I tried to iterate from 0 to len(list), but len returns an integer so I can't iterate over it. Next I tried iterating from 0 to range(len(list)) because 'range' returns a list of integers from 0 to len(list). However I get a key error

```
for index in range(len(objectName.listName)):
    print("\n\t listName[%i]: %s" % (index, objectName.listName[index]))
```

When I execute the above code all the elements in the list get printed but then the iterator trys to access an element which is outside the range, and I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filename.py", line 276, in 
    print("\n\t listName[%i]: %s" % (index, objectName.listName[index]))
KeyError: 10

I expected to see each element printed out.

Note: There are only 10 elements (indexed 0 -> 9 ) but the iterator trys to access "key:10".

Comment: what is the output of len(objectName.listName)?

Comment: @ IllllIll Santhosh Kumar IllllI The output of this is as expected. It outputs listName[index]: INTEGER, where index is [0, 9] depending on which iteration it is on and INTEGER is the int value stored in listName at the respective index

Comment: What is the output of len command showed? 10?

Comment: @IllllIll Santhosh Kumar IllllI Calling the len command on objectName.listName returns the value 11

Answer (score 0):

```
for index in range(len(objectName.listName)-1):
    print("\n\t listName[%i]: %s" % (index, objectName.listName[index]))
```

Because len(objectName.listName) returns 11

range(11) = 0,1,2...10

Comment: @ IllllIll Santhosh Kumar IllllI I agree with your assertion but this does not answer the question. I am acquiring the length by calling the len function on the list and then using this as a bound while I iterate over the list. Since I am getting the end bound from the length of the list itself then why is the iterator trying to access an index outside this bound?

Comment: the len function returns 11 instead of 10 thats why the range goes beyond 9

Comment: But it I acquire this length from the list itself then try to iterate over this range. How is it not the correct range of the list? e.g. creating a list as follows: list1=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] then doing a print: print(len(list1)) will return 10. If I then do the following: for index in range(len(list1)): print("%i" % index) I will get the following: 0123456789 with no problem. So why is it not the same in the original question?

Comment: for that I need to know more about objectName.listName
Can you print that variable to see how many elements?

Comment: Print the variable yields the following: listName[0]: (6, 1, 1), listName[1]: (6, 1, 4), listName[2]: (6, 1, 4),   listName[3]: (6, 1, 6), listName[4]: (6, 1, 5), listName[5]: (6, 1, 2), listName[6]: (6, 1, 8),  listName[7]: (6, 1, 3), listName[8]: (6, 1, 4), listName[9]: (6, 1, 7). NOTE: Each element in the list is a tuple

Comment: did you manually got all the output like listName[0] listName[1]... ?
because I tried locally but i couldnt see it.